# New build won't power up

Tags: boot, motherboard, post

I just finished putting together a new build, and nothing powers up (no power LED, no fans, nothing) , except for the STDBY LED on the motherboard. It is a micro-ATX motherboard.

I tried the paper clip trick to test the PSU , and the fan did power on. Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Try unplugging and replugging everything. If that doesn't work it may also help to check if any pins are bent, if any wires or secretly frayed, if there are gnomes in your computer, etc.
Also, what processor, fans, PSU, etc. specifically?

Comment: Did you correctly connect the power/reset switches?

Comment: Did it beep at all? Is the PSU strong enough to drive everything? Does your GPU require its own power? Is everything seated properly? We need more details.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this is most frequently caused by the power switch being either not correctly connected to the motherboard, or (in one fairly spectacular case) mechanically faulty. Anyway, after the PSU that'd be the first thing I'd check.

Answer (score 0):

Do a bit by bit troubleshooting could be due to static that causes the hardware to fail.

Remove one ram stick at a time and power up.
If it is still not working remove the graphic card and try to power up.

Listen closely to the Bios speaker BEEP sound.

Answer (score 0):

My experience, too,  would say it is incorrect or corrupted memory. But also, check in to the power supply unit too.

Also found this link on... [How to Bench Test Your System](http://www.techsupportforum.com/hardware-support/building/171424-how-bench-test-your-system.html)

Comment: Also, did it ever power up?

Comment: If the memory is faulty, it should power up but do something like continuously beep.

Comment: @ultrasawblade - You are right. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote this answer.